# Полностью сломался проект, нужна помощь

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Совершенно не понимаю что произошло, но при создание новой активности у меня сломался весь проект.
Вот какие строки теперь в файле build.gradle (module) :

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
package com.example.mymovie;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuestList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView info;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
```

В gradle-wrapper.properties вот такая история:

```
    package com.example.mymovie;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
impo
```

И все, больше там ничего нет.

sync project with gradle files не помогает.

Новые проекты вообще не собираются,

Comment: Проект был под версионным контролем?

Comment: Я больше чем уверен, что Android studio сама хранит историю файлов, можете посмотреть там.

Comment: Что значит "новые проекты вообще не собираются"?